# Is it possible to create query to execute multiple queries in one query in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, execution

I would like to send multiple queries as a string. 
I returned the result as an object by javascript. 
however, it has an error because of "," between queries.
I couldn't remove "," between queries.

```
    "INSERT INTO  membership ( userId,roleId,groupId )
    VALUES (5,1,5),
    INSERT INTO  membership ( userId,roleId,groupId )
    VALUES (5,1,4),
    INSERT INTO  membership ( userId,roleId,groupId )
    VALUES (5,1,5)"
```

Is it possible to execute multiple queries in one query?

this is javascript code what I returned the string.

```
var objArray = [];
for (var i =0; i< obj.length ;i++) {
objArray.push( " INSERT INTO membership(id,userId,roleId,groupId) VALUES (" 
obj[i].id + "," +  obj[i].userId  + "," + obj[i].role + "," + obj[i].group + 
")");
 } 
 return objArray.toString();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will they be insert queries?

Comment: yes I would like to insert multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Use `;` instead of `,`. Example `QUERY1;QUERY2;QUERY3`

Comment: the queries from a variable. I am struggling to remove  ,

Answer (score 0):

Go for a multiple insert query

```
var beforeQuery = 'INSERT INTO membership(id,userId,roleId,groupId) VALUES ';
var qvalues = [];
for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
   qvalues.push('(' + obj[i].id + ',' + 
   obj[i].userId  + ',' + 
   obj[i].role + ',' + 
   obj[i].group + ')');
} 

var query = beforeQuery + qvalues.join(",");
// result would be something like:
// INSERT INTO membership(id,userId,roleId,groupId) VALUES (1,2,3,4),(3,5,3,6),(2,5,19,2);

// execute query here with query variable, all rows will be inserted with a single query
```

Comment: And if you want to combine different kind of queries, you should create a procedure:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html
It will execute all queries at once, and you can even do rollbacks

Comment: thanks for the answer. My apologies I didn't mention about the validation of the query. The whole query need the statement such as: IF ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   membership  where mid = 1111))